# Javacript [ document.write ("___"); ] Shortcut to not start each line with document.write ("

Tags: javascript, html

In this code I want to insert some HTML and normal text in JavaScript and don't want it to always enter `document.write("` in starting of each line like:

```js
document.write("some text
some text
some text");
```

Instead of this:

```js
document.write("Hello World!");
document.write("Have a nice day!");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<p>some random paragraph");
```

```js
document.write("Hello World!");
document.write("Have a nice day!");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<p>some random paragraph");
```

Comment: You have a few options.  I would start with looking into template literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ⚠Warning: Don't use document.write

Instead use document.body.innerHTML = '';

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `
your text
<br>
your text
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [Don't use `document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> ⚠ Warning: Use of the document.write() method is strongly discouraged.

2. Use a [template/string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create the HTML, and then assign it to the `innerHTML` of the document body (or whatever element you want).

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `
  Hello World!<br />
  Have a nice day!<br />
  <p>some random paragraph</p>
`;
```

Comment: with your code sometimes all code fades and only code in script shows and also i cant add css(style) in that html file. BTW Thanks

Comment: _"sometimes all code fades"_: I'm not quite sure what that means.